# $V$ the graph of a differentiable function?

Tags: differential-geometry

Consider this proposition in differential geometry:

> Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3 $ be a regular surface and $p \in S$. Then
>   there exists a neighborhood $V$ of $p$ in $S$ such that $V$ is the
>   graph of a differentiable function which has one of the following
>   three forms: $z = f(x,y)$, $y = g(x,z)$, $x = h(y,z)$

I'm a bit confused by this proposition in Do Carmo, because by a neighborhood of $p$, it seems like $V$ is at least some $2$ dimensional piece of surface - but the functions mentioned above seem like functions from $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, so is $V$ just a curve?

Would be great if someone could help clear my confusion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graph of a function from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$ is a surface, not a curve. For every pair $(x,y)$, you have the value $f(x,y)$, so you have a surface parametrised as $$(x,y,f(x,y))$$ which is a two dimensional object.

Comment: oh right right. Thanks very much, the notation just confused me a bit. Why do we not say it is a function from $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow    \mathbb{R}^3$? What is the difference here?

Comment: @LoLo A "graph" of a "function" (because, technically, only mappings to $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ are really *functions*) from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R^3$ would be an object that naturally exists in $\mathbb R^5$...

Comment: @LoLo I think I know what is confusing you. A **curve** is not an object that maps from $X$ to $\mathbb R$, but the other way around! A curve is a function $f:\mathbb R\to X$, because that is a function that, for every point in "time" (parametrised by $\mathbb R$) tells you your location.